# How to create custom page inside Django 2 admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I need create a custom page inside **Django 2.1.4** admin with admin styles, breadcrumbs e.t. support.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', include([
        path('', admin.site.urls),
        path('test/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="admin/test.html"), name="admin-test"),
    ])),
    ...
]
```

**templates/admin/base.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block welcome-msg %}    
    <a href="{% url 'admin-test' %}">admin test page</a>    
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

**templates/admin/test.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>admin/test.html</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

My page looks like this:
[image: Django empty admin]

Page is created, but header content is diapered: no user-tools, no branding info. I've tried to add *{{ block.super }}* inside *block content* but no effect.

Will be very appreciate for any tips how to make my template correctly inherit form base.